# list control is not working on first click?

Tags: mfc

I have a two item in list control in mfc .On clicking on each item i am doing something.but fist time when i clicked nothing effecting.after second clicking everything working fine.what will be the reason.

Comment: Could we have some code for your OnClick function?

Comment: I am just changing variable. I got the solution but i am not sure whether its correct way.i have override onclick function of the list.Now its working fine.I don't know the reason.

Comment: I had a related issue: When clicking an item that had previously been selected, nothing happens. So I had to call the code that handles selection in 
void CMyListCtrl::OnNMClickListCtrl(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult).